# compute the volume of the solid E

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume, multiple-integral

The points (x,y,z) of this solid projected on the plane z=0 are in the parallelogram (2,1),(6,-1),(7,0),(3,2) and $\le z \le e^{x+2y}$.

$$\int_{2}^{7}dx \int_{-0.5x+2}^{-0.5x+3.5}dy \int_{0}^{e^{x+2y}}dz$$
 is right?

the result of my book is $2(e^7-e^4)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The black bordered region is what you are supposed to be integrating over. The red extensions are the additional areas your integral is including.

[image: Boundary mismatch]

You need to set up different limitations on $y$ for $2 < x < 3$ than for $3 < x < 6$, and different limitations again for $6 < x < 7$. It is helpful to express it as the sum of 3 integrals, rather than a single integral.

An alternative method is to do a change of variables $(u, v) = g(x,y)$ for an appropriate mapping $g$ that will convert this parallelogram into a rectangle in $(u,v)$ space with horizontal and vertical edges. I'll leave it to you to figure out what expression of $u,v$ in terms of $(x,y)$ will do that.